# How is this syntax called?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I've already used the new syntax for a while, and now I'd like to know more about it:

```
function func({ foo, bar }) {
    console.log(foo, bar);
}

func({ foo: "my-foo", bar: "my-bar" });
```

The part of syntax that I'm asking about is the way of declaring the arguments in curly braces.

Comment: These are object literals. You can read more about these on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just `Property shorthand` syntax, which is part of ES6 implementation.

```
function func({ foo, bar }) {
```

is nothing but

```
function func({ foo: foo, bar: bar }) {
```

http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching

Comment: But how he is able to use `foo` and `bar` in the `console.log`?

Comment: It is part of `Destructuring Assignment` in the context of 
`Parameter Context Matching`